# I cant configure google drive backup onmy Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, backup, laravel-backup

Im trying to setup a backup for my Laravel project using Spatie laravel Backup package but i cant install Flysystem adapter for Google Drive i get the error
`- Root composer.json requires nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive ~1.1 -> satisfiable by nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.13].
- nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive[1.1.0, ..., 1.1.13] require league/flysystem ~1.0 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.10] but the package is fixed to 3.14.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error but I was able to make backups in Google drive using: [masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext](https://github.com/masbug/flysystem-google-drive-ext)
The usage and configuration is almost the same as pon/flysystem-google-drive.
There is an error with this package tho, you have to set the backup name to "" in the spatie backup config to make it work.